# Parse data into struct efficiently by reducing memory footprint

Tags: go

I have a simple program where I am deserializing my bytes `byteSlice` into a `ClientProduct` array struct. And then I iterate over that `ClientProduct` array and construct `definitions.CustomerProduct` struct for each `ClientProduct`.

Below is my struct details:

```
type ProductInfo struct {
    Name map[Locale]map[int]string
}

type Locale string

type CustomerProduct struct {
    Prs            string
    ProductId      int64
    Catalogs       []int32
    Categories     []int
    BaseProductId  *int64
    StatusCode     int
    IsActive       bool
    Common
}

type ValueMetrics struct {
    Value    string
    ClientId int64
}

type Common struct {
    Leagues []ValueMetrics
    Teams   []ValueMetrics
    ProductInfo
}
```

Here is the code which deserializes `byteSlice` into `ClientProduct` array struct by using `Convert` and few other helper methods.

```
var productRows []ClientProduct
err = json.Unmarshal(byteSlice, &productRows)
if err != nil {
  return errs.Wrap(err)
}

for i := range productRows {
  var flatProduct definitions.CustomerProduct
  err = r.Convert(spn, &productRows[i], &flatProduct)
  if err != nil {
    return errs.Wrap(err)
  }

  if flatProduct.StatusCode == definitions.DONE {
    continue
  }

  // populate map here from each "flatProduct"
}
```

Here is my `Convert` method which populates my `CustomerProduct` struct. And few other helper methods which help to populate `CustomerProduct` struct

```
func (r *clientRepo) Convert(span log.Span, in *ClientProduct, out *definitions.CustomerProduct) error {
    commons, err := r.getCommonStruct(span, in)
    if err != nil {
        return errs.Wrap(err)
    }

    out.Common = commons
    out.Catalogs = r.convertParquetIntSliceToInt32Slice(in.Catalogs)
    out.Categories = in.Categories
    out.ProductId = in.Id
    out.IsActive = in.IsActive
    out.Prs = in.PRS
    out.StatusCode = in.StatusCode

    return nil
}

func (r *clientRepo) getCommonStruct(span log.Span, in *ClientProduct) (definitions.Common, error) {
    out := definitions.Common{}

    for _, pv := range in.PropertyValues {
        switch pv.Name {
        case "ABC":
            out.Leagues = r.concatStringSlice(pv, out.Leagues)
        case "DEF":
            out.Teams = r.concatStringSlice(pv, out.Teams)
        }
    }

    for _, opv := range in.OverriddenPropertyValues {
        switch opv.Name {
        case "CustomerName":
            if opv.Locale == "" {
                // log error
            } else {
                out.Name = r.attach(definitions.Locale(opv.Locale), opv, out.Name)
            }
        }
    }

    return out, nil
}

func (r *clientRepo) concatStringSlice(pv PropertyValue, list []definitions.ValueMetrics) []definitions.ValueMetrics {
    treeValue := definitions.ValueMetrics{Value: pv.Value, ClientId: pv.ClientId}
    if list == nil {
        return []definitions.ValueMetrics{treeValue}
    }
    return append(list, treeValue)
}

func (r *clientRepo) attach(locale definitions.Locale, opv OverriddenPropertyValue, m map[definitions.Locale]map[int]string) map[definitions.Locale]map[int]string {
    if m == nil {
        om := map[int]string{
            opv.GroupId: opv.Value,
        }
        return map[definitions.Locale]map[int]string{
            locale: om,
        }
    }

    os, ok := m[locale]
    if ok {
        os[opv.GroupId] = opv.Value
        m[locale] = os
    } else {
        m[locale] = map[int]string{
            opv.GroupId: opv.Value,
        }
    }

    return m
}

func (r *clientRepo) convertParquetIntSliceToInt32Slice(catalogs []int) []int32 {
    var out []int32
    for _, catalog := range catalogs {
        out = append(out, int32(catalog))
    }
    return out
}
```

**Problem Statement**

Above code works fine. Basically looking for code review on the way I am populating "CustomerProduct" using all these helper methods. Anything that can be improved?

- I am looking for inputs or ideas where I can improve the way I am populating `CustomerProduct` struct by using all those helper methods I have starting with `Convert` method.
- Also is there anything that can be improved in above code which can help in our memory footprint? Like using pointer's or passing reference of it instead of direct passing.

I am seeing some memory fluctuating a lot whenever this deserialization happens and `CustomerProduct` struct is populated from all those helper methods. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to have a benchmark before you start trying to optimize the code. That being said, I can think of a few general recommendations.

- The `ProductInfo.Name` field is a nested map, this will require a lot of maps to be allocated. Instead of nested maps, consider defining a struct key type, something like

  ```golang
  type NameKey struct {
      Locale  Locale
      GroupID int
  }

  type ProductInfo struct {
      Name map[NameKey]string
  }
  ```

  Then `getCommonStruct` might look like

  ```golang
  func (r *clientRepo) getCommonStruct(span log.Span, in ClientProduct) (definitions.Common, error) {
      out := definitions.Common{
          // Initialize Name ahead of time.
          ProductInfo: definitions.ProductInfo {
              Name: make(map[definitions.NameKey]string),
          },
      }

      for _, pv := range in.PropertyValues {
          // This part is the same.
          ...
      }

      for _, opv := range in.OverriddenPropertyValues {
          switch opv.Name {
          case "CustomerName":
              if opv.Locale == "" {
                  ...
                  continue
              }
              // Just set the value in the map.
              out.Name[NameKey{Locale: definitions.Locale(opv.Locale), GroupID: opv.GroupID}] = opv.Value
          }
      }

      return out, nil
  }
  ```
- In general prefer passing values instead of pointers. This tends to produce code that is easier to read and reason about. Computers are really fast at copying memory :) Of course, if your benchmark tells you a pointer is faster somewhere, feel free to use that.
- The `Convert` method can return a `CustomerProduct` instead of using an out parameter. I would also recommend taking the ClientProduct by value since it isn't modified.
- The `concatStringSlice` helper can be simplified, `append` works just fine on `nil`:

  ```golang
  func (r *clientRepo) concatStringSlice(pv PropertyValue, list []definitions.ValueMetrics) []definitions.ValueMetrics {
      return append(list, definitions.ValueMetrics{Value: pv.Value, ClientId: pv.ClientId})
  }
  ```
- In `convertParquetIntSliceToInt32Slice`, `out` can be pre-allocated to the right size:

  ```golang
  func (r *clientRepo) convertParquetIntSliceToInt32Slice(catalogs []int) []int32 {
      out := make([]int32, 0, len(catalogs))
      for _, catalog := range catalogs {
         out = append(out, int32(catalog))
      }
      return out
  }
  ```

Sorry for the typos it's late :)

Comment: Thanks for your good suggestion. I am looking into all those. If possible can you add example on `pt1` and `pt4` on how those method will look like with suggested change? This will help me understand better.

Comment: Updated with some examples of how the methods might look

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. In the `attach` method, I was mainly looking for if `m` is nil then how should I deal with that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Set `out.Name = make(map[NameKey]string)` before calling `attach`. It simplifies the `attach` function to assume the map has already been initialized.

Comment: I see. So my attach function returns the map but in your case it doesn't return it right? so my else block will look like this then? `else {
  out.Name = make(map[NameKey]string)
  out.Name = r.attach(definitions.Locale(opv.Locale), opv, out.Name)
}` or I got it wrong? I initialize the map before calling attach. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I added an example of what `getCommonStruct` might look like

Comment: `definitions.Common` doesn't have `Name` field right? So when I try to use your suggested code, it complains for me as that key doesn't exist in that struct. Let me know if my understanding is correct.